# Can't set my navigation bar background image properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a view, and inside this view I have a table view.

I want to change this table view navigation bar image to some image.

So I added a navigation bar object in the interface builder and put it on the table view > I control dragged from this object to the table view controller > then in the viewDidLoad I adder the line: `[self.navBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];`

With navBar is the outlet to the navigation bar.

Why this does not work?

tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, Navigation Bar should display the background image with the method you used until and unless the project resources contain the image and Navigation Bar is referenced properly.

Anyways, you can embed the View in Navigation Controller
1. Select ViewController in Storyboard
2. Go to Editor -> Embed in -> Navigation Controller 
and use the following code in viewDidAppear-

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: I tried the ideal way before and it didn't work either...and I dont use storyboard, just nib files

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding the below code in AppDelegate

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: this is showing me both now, I see the default nav bar and the custom one under it...and also since its in app delegate so other screens that i pop to get this black bg. but its the first time i actually see the image so its progress, do you know how to get over the issues i mentioned?